# Can I use MERGE statement to use insert, update and delete clauses on 2 or more tables through one operation?

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I can not find this information in documentation, also cant find any information about possibility this operation in other internet resources.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use `MERGE` to change two or more tables in one operation.

The syntax of `MERGE` in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) has only one bubble for a table or a view. Theoretically, a view could consist of more than one table, but `MERGE` will not work on such a view.

EDIT: No, `MERGE` on a view that joins more than one table doesn't work:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, c1 VARCHAR2(30));
CREATE TABLE t2 (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES t1(id), c2 VARCHAR2(30));
CREATE TABLE m  (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE VIEW  v12 AS SELECT t1.id, t1.c1, t2.c2 FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id;
INSERT INTO  t1 VALUES(1, 'BEFORE');
INSERT INTO  t2 VALUES(1, 'before');
INSERT INTO  m  VALUES(1);

SELECT * FROM v12;
ID C1     C2
1  BEFORE before

`MERGE` causes an error:

MERGE INTO v12 USING m ON (v12.id = m.id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set c1='AFTER';

ORA-38106: MERGE not supported on join view or view with INSTEAD OF trigger.
*Action:   When using MERGE to modify a view, you must only specify a single
           table in the view, and the view cannot have an INSTEAD OF trigger.
```

However, `UPDATE` works, but only if one underlying table is affected:

```
UPDATE v12 SET c1='AFTER';
1 row updated.

UPDATE v12 SET c2='after';
1 row updated.

UPDATE v12 SET c1='AFTER', c2='after';
SQL Error: ORA-01776: cannot modify more than one base table through a join view
```

Comment: If a view pulls data from multiple tables it becomes uneditable, if my memory is correct. You *could*, of course, create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view to handle this - so, I suppose that you could say that it's **indirectly** possible to MERGE UPDATE and INSERT into multiple tables at once - but that's thanks to using other features of the database, as the MERGE statement itself can only have a single target.

Comment: @wolφi  A view can definitely be based out of more than one table.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica, sadly, it doesn't work.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica yes, I'm a dog. You got me at `OPEN c; LOOP FETCH`... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A MERGE statement can only have a single target, and thus can only INSERT or UPDATE a single table. It cannot be used to modify more than a single table at once, unless (as @wolφi suggests below) the target of the MERGE is a view with an INSTEAD OF trigger which then modifies multiple tables.